# SQL: Regexp_replace but only the first time a value appears in record

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, mariadb, regexp-replace

I am coding an plugin for [harbiforum](https://www.harbiforum.net). I have post content in the message column.

I want to search and replace pattern with X but only the first time pattern appears in the record as it may appear more than once.

The below query would obviously replace all instances of pattern with X

```
UPDATE xf_post SET message = REGEXP_REPLACE (message, 'pattern', 'X');
```

It's very easy with this command on oracle db.

```
UPDATE xf_post SET message = REGEXP_REPLACE (message , 'pattern', 'X', 1, 1);
```

But the server has mariadb  I don't know how to do it.

Comment: In MariaDB there is no additional parameters which allows to set the amount of replaces, all occurences are replaced always. And there is no easy way to emulate this when the replacement pattern contains references to found pattern groups. If the replacement is a literal then find the pattern with REGEXP_INSTR(), define its position and length, then strip it and replace using two SUBSTRING().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of the REGEXP_REPLACE emulation with 1st occurence replacement only.

```sql
SELECT txt,
       CONCAT(LEFT(txt, LOCATE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(txt,'pattern'), txt) - 1),
              REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(txt,'pattern'), 'pattern', 'replacement'),
              SUBSTRING(txt FROM LOCATE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(txt,'pattern'), txt) + LENGTH(REGEXP_SUBSTR(txt,'pattern')))) output
FROM test
```

[fiddle with the explanations](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=b51f60b09674df5b19174a69d19af1cf)